# Render tabs as vertical tree

Tags: 7, routes

How do I render `$tabs` used in **page.tpl.php**, not horizontally, but as a vertical tree so the secondary tabs will be placed under/in the parent?

**This is what I got:**

```
<h2 class="element-invisible">Primary tabs</h2>
<ul class="tabs primary">
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
</ul>
<h2 class="element-invisible">Secondary tabs</h2>
<ul class="tabs secondary">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Child item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Child item 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

**This is how I want it to be:**

```
<h2 class="element-invisible">Primary tabs</h2>
<ul class="tabs primary">
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li class="active">
        <a href="#">Item 2</a>
        <h2 class="element-invisible">Secondary tabs</h2>
        <ul class="tabs secondary">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Child item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Child item 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How do I achieve this without using javascript? I'm currently using `render($tabs);` to get something similar to the output above.

Answer (score 0):

Basically after examining the code example from the [example module](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/vertical_tabs_example%21vertical_tabs_example.module/7), I've found that the **vertical_tabs** are the container of the different **fieldsets**, and the title of the **fieldset** is the vertical tab's title.
All tabs are connected to the **vertical_tabs** through the  **#group** attribute. It's that simple...

```
$form['additional_settings'] = array(
         '#type' => 'vertical_tabs',
         '#weight' => 99,
      );

      $form['vertical_tabs_example2'] = array(
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
      '#title' => t('Example vertical tab2'),
      '#collapsible' => TRUE,
      '#collapsed' => FALSE,
      // The #group value must match the name of the vertical tabs element.
      // In most cases, this is 'additional_settings'.
      '#group' => 'additional_settings',
      // Attach the javascript for vertical tabs.
      '#attached' => array(
        'js' => array(
          'vertical-tabs' => drupal_get_path('module', 'vertical_tabs_example') . '/vertical_tabs_example.js',
        ),
      ),
      '#tree' => TRUE,
      '#weight' => -2,
    );

      $form['vertical_tabs_example'] = array(
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
      '#title' => t('Example vertical tab1'),
      '#collapsible' => TRUE,
      '#collapsed' => FALSE,
      // The #group value must match the name of the vertical tabs element.
      // In most cases, this is 'additional_settings'.
      '#group' => 'additional_settings',
      // Attach the javascript for vertical tabs.
      '#attached' => array(
        'js' => array(
          'vertical-tabs' => drupal_get_path('module', 'vertical_tabs_example') . '/vertical_tabs_example.js',
        ),
      ),
      '#tree' => TRUE,
      '#weight' => -2,
    );
```